# Why am I getting vertical and horizontal gaps between inline blocks?

Tags: html, css

```css
.blockType {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inlineType {
  display: inline;
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.inlineBlockType {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="blockType">
    block1
  </div>
  <div class="inlineType">
    inline1
  </div>
  <div class="inlineBlockType">
    inline-block1
  </div>
  <div class="inlineType">
    inline2
  </div>
  <div class="blockType">
    block2
  </div>
</body>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/1sharth/pen/qBdaKGe?editors=1100

I noticed that whenever I change the font-size of the inline1 element, these gaps change. I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: why I can't  reply ?

Comment: @fatihdurna The question is closed and so answers can't be posted